# Making out the correct expression of probability.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Here is the image of the question:
 [probability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUS8i.png)

It is written that we need to take probability of occurrence of **at least one of A and B**. Shouldn't it mean an occurrence that belongs to both A and B and is occurs at least one?? I am all confused by the statement of the question.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please type your questions rather than posting a link to an image since links can get broken and images cannot be searched.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  At least one of $A$ and $B$ means $A$ occurs, $B$ occurs, or both $A$ and $B$ occur, that is, we are looking for the occurrence of an event in $A \cup B$.

Answer (score 0):

I am actually confused as to what your precise confusion is :p ...particularly this question:

> "Shouldn't it mean an occurrence that belongs to both A and B and is occurs at least one??"

If it helps visualize things...

[image]

As far as what the blue text in your image is saying, note that the probability that $A$ or $B$ occurs is one minus the probability that neither occurs:

$$P(A\cup B)=1-P((A\cup B)')=1-P(A'\cap B').$$

If $A,B$ are independent, then $A',B'$ are also independent (*why?*), and thus

$$P(A'\cap B')=P(A')P(B').$$